# Image isn't visible in my site

Tags: image

I've just added a simple code (`<img src="images/2.jpg"/>`) in my WordPress website. But it's not working. [Check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA7Qx.png)

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Also I've tried it in different theme but same result. I've never seen this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add this code (`<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>`) to make it dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try add leading slash to your image path to start at the root directory instead of your current directory where your code is located:

```
<img src="/images/2.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely the path is incorrect. images is not immediate directory to your current page directory.
usually in wordpress images are in wp-content/uploads/2017/05/%some_image.jpg%

Answer (score 0):

you are using  `<img src="path"/>` you can solve this issue by adding the url of the image like ‪C:\Users\Hitesh Kumar\Desktop\xyz.jpg.
but i know that you are using wordpress so you can add the image by its url like `<img src="www.site_name/image.jpg"/>`
hope it will help